# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un método genérico que me convierta una lista de tipo, list<object>.object.variable a un list<object>.variable?

Tags: java, lista

Necesito crear un método genérico que me permita pasar un tipo de listas a otro, no sé como hacerlo :c

Voy a recibir listas con este formato:
`List<Channels> channelsList= new ArrayList<>();`
Donde el objeto Channels, tiene esto

```
public class Channels {
    private Channel channel;
}
```

Y el objeto Channel, trae las variables

```
public class Channel {
        private String id;
        private String name;
}
```

Eso lo quiero pasar a una lista que tendrá el siguiente formato:

`List<ChannelsDto> channelsList= new ArrayList<>();`

Donde el objeto ChannelsDto, tiene las variables

```
public class ChannelsDto {
        private String id;
        private String name;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando el API Streams sería relativamente simple y legible.

```
channelsList.stream()
        .map(Channels::getChannel)
        .map(this::toChannelDto)
        .toList();
```

Este sería el método `toChannelDto()`.

```
private ChannelDto toChannelDto(Channel channel) {
    return new ChannelDto(channel.getId(), channel.getName());
}
```

Si el `ChannelDto` tuviera un constructor que reciba un `Channel` podrías usarlo en lugar del método `toChannelDto()`.

```
channelsList.stream()
        .map(Channels::getChannel)
        .map(ChannelDto::new)
        .toList();
```